# Find references to one database's columns in all other databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want these 5 columns as output when a stored procedure, in *any* database on the server, references a column in a specific database (let's say the database is `AA`).

```
Column_name  Table_Name   Schema_Name   Procedure_Name   Database_Name
```

Comment: I don't think it can be done precisely, at least because of dynamic SQL may be used in stored proc.

Comment: Also because you could have synonyms defined in other databases and your column references may use complicated names / table aliases like `database..table AS t` or `database..[table] AS t1` - now you have to parse all of the code for references to any `t.column` or `t1.column` and hope that they're prefixed (they're not always because people are lazy).

Comment: Yes, you guys are right. Can I get tables used in all procedures as they will be used in format [schema].[table_name], I will check those procedures for columns manually to list them.

Answer (score 1):

Four of the columns are really easy to get - for the current database that you're in:

```
SELECT
    TableName = t.Name,
    SchemaName = s.Name,
    ColumnName = c.Name,
    DatabaseName = DB_NAME()
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN
    sys.schemas s ON [t].[schema_id] = [s].[schema_id]
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns c ON [t].[object_id] = [c].[object_id]
```

What you cannot get easily is **all** columns across **all tables in all databases**. Also: determining in which procedure each column is used is also rather tricky (or next to impossible).

Comment: Thanks for Quick reply Marc. I  need info of all the columns in a particular database used in all procedures of all databases. Is it possible? Say if a column 'CC' is used in particular db 'AA' and in particular procedure 'PP', I need the output CC PP AA.

Comment: @marc_S Can we do something with `sys.sysdepends` table?

Comment: @user2666339: as I said - no, getting that information (*which column is used in which procedure*) is ***NOT*** easy at all. You would almost have to load all the procedure's T-SQL code and parse it.....

Comment: @Nithesh: that only tells you which **tables** (or views etc.) a procedure depends on - it doesn't go to the *column* level....

Comment: @marc_s i generated a query from your answer which gives comma seperated string of sp names (dependent by the table). kindly have a look and comment pls

Comment: @marc_s IF YOU SEE MY LAST QUESTION, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138464/list-all-columns-referenced-in-all-procedures-of-all-databases ANSWERED BY Aaron Bertrand. From that query I can get all the columns used in all procedures for all databases. Please take a look.

Comment: @user2666339: ok, then you already **have** the solution ! Just combine it as needed and off you go ....

Comment: @marc_s That query returns all the columns listed in all the procedures of all the databases. But it won't say me that the column is from "X" database. I am not able to get that, I tried things. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From `marc_s` answer i generate a query which gives comma separated Procedure_Name depended by that table

```
 SELECT
    TableName = t.Name,
    SchemaName = s.Name,
    ColumnName = c.Name,
    DatabaseName = DB_NAME(),
    STUFF((SELECT  ',' +  name 
         FROM sys.procedures
         WHERE object_id in (SELECT distinct id from sys.sysdepends
                                WHERE depid = (SELECT object_id FROM sys.tables
                                                WHERE name=t.Name)
                              )
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 0, '') AS sps
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN
    sys.schemas s ON [t].[schema_id] = [s].[schema_id]
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns c ON [t].[object_id] = [c].[object_id]
```

Comment: With the above query, I am getting only the list of procedures in the database which used (need to validate though got some info). Is there a way I can get all the info in all SPs of all the databases. Thanks.

Comment: It returned all the columns in a particular table as if all are used even though only few of the columns were used in a stored procedure.