# How to get the list of all tables and columns referenced in a SQl Script

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a bunch of complex SQL scripts which refer to multiple databases. I would like to get a comprehensive list of all columns and tables specified in each script (be it in the Select list or computations, or conditions, or joins, or derived tables/CTEs).

I found this: [List all columns referenced in all procedures of all databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138464/list-all-columns-referenced-in-all-procedures-of-all-databases)
Not sure if that can be tweaked for my purpose.

Any help/input is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You will receive better answers if you demonstrate what specific things you have tried and what specific thing you are stuck on. Did you try the solution from the other answer?

Comment: Could you clarify a bit, I am not sure if you want all the columns for a set of tables or all the columns and tables in a script you are using. The link deals with finding info on tables/columns in stored procedures

Comment: @Sean, thanks! I've tried executing the other query but I got dependency errors. Anyways, I'm not trying to look at Stored Procedures. I have tried using sys.sql_dependencies to figure out dependencies for the table (the bunch of scripts I have populate this table), but I got nothing there.

Comment: @orgtigger, I have a bunch of scripts that populate a table from multiple tables and databases. I need to trace each column of my table to one or more columns from which it is populated. The scripts are complex with lots of calculations, derived tables, joins.